# Recordmydesktop stucks encoding the video file. File produced is only 8 min instead of hours

Tags: video, screencast, recordmydesktop

I did a very long screencast with `recordmydesktop` (almost two hours).

At the end of the recording, `recordmydesktop` started encoding all the raw data it recorded to produce an `out.ogv` video file, as usual.

However, it is now unable to totally create that file. The encoding process is starting normally, `out.ogv` is created and starts to grow, but that stops at 1 209 585 664 bytes (the video is 8min11 long). `recordmydesktop` says nothing, it looks like it just continues to render, but nothing happens anymore. After a time, my computer just froze, I guess the RAM and the SWAP were full. The video was still 8min11.

I was afraid I loose my all work, but I found the raw files of `recordmydesktop` hidden in the `/tmp/rmMD-session-4625/` directory. This folder is 50GB, so my screencast definitely is there. I searched the doc and found the `--rescue` option, allowing to restart the encoding process.
I launched it again and let it that way the whole night, and this morning, the processus is stopped, and the new video file is still exactly the same than the first try, stopped at 8min11.

The output of the terminal:

```
recordmydesktop --rescue /tmp/rMD-session-4625/
Restoring /tmp/rMD-session-4625/!!!
STATE:ENCODING
Encoding started!
This may take several minutes.
Pressing Ctrl-C will cancel the procedure (resuming will not be possible, but
any portion of the video, which is already encoded won't be deleted).
Please wait...
Output file: out-4.ogv
[0%] Processus arrêté0]
```

Here is the content of the `specs.txt` file in the `rMD-session-4625` folder:

```
recordMyDesktop = 0.3.8.1
Width = 1920
Height = 1072
Filename = out.ogv
FPS = 15.000000
NoSound = 0
Frequency = 22050
Channels = 1
BufferSize = 4096
SoundFrameSize = 2
PeriodSize = 1365
UsedJack = 0
v_bitrate = 0
v_quality = 63
s_quality = 10
ZeroCompression = 1
```

I know `recordmydesktop` is a pretty old program. Is there a limitation of the output file size? If so, can't it produce several small files that I would then be able to concate? I backuped the content of the folder to be sure to not loose my raw files in `/tmp/`, but I'm stuck on what to do. I can't loose that work!

**Edit:** Okay, I tried it the big way: I created a 65GB swapfile. With my 16GB RAM, this gave 80GB to RecordMyDesktop to encode the video. And I had the same behaviour, the file stopped growing at 1.2GB. I let RMD continues, it used 100% of one CPU core during 4 days and filled totally the 80GB of RAM it had available, without changing anything to the result. I thought as the raw files are 50GB, once it had it in RAM, it would do something, but no.

The source code of the program is available but I'm rusty with C. I contacted the developer without any answer. The raw files are un YUV420 but I was unable to convert them with ffmpeg. Please help!

Comment: Do you remember `ffmpeg` arguments that you used? What error message did you get?